# Issue with UIImage and iOS 8 when loading JPEG image from Library

Tags: iphone, ios8, uiimageview, jpeg

I have issue with loading image from /Library/ in both iPhone Simulator and on the real device.

This issue happened on only iOS-8.

Could any one please tell me what is the issue and how can I resolve it.

Thanks you in advance.

== Additional Information ==

Here is the code I load image from Library folder of my app.

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.photoGraph.imageFileName];
```

Scenerio:

1. We have package data to be downloaded from the Internet
2. Extract downloaded data to /Library/Caches/data/
3. Load image from extracted folder

It worked fine from iOS 7 and prior

## On iOS8 it has error as image below

Original image

[image]

Loaded image

[image: Loaded JPG file from ...]

Comment: You'll have to give us more details for us to be able to help you. This could be anything.

Comment: Thanks @bgilham, I just updated my question to put more information. If you known the issue please help us.

Comment: Maybe you call the image with .png at the end (like assets catalog problem) ?

Comment: It may not the case because I printed the absolute path to the console and it showed like this ImageFileName: /Users/buithevinh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/98324CCC-423C-4A4B-AE3F-F59723AAF63B/data/Containers/Data/Application/4D250819-AE67-473D-9451-9BEEBD45B44B/Library/Caches/data/package02/025.jpg